# How to implement such tool-tip in open-flash-chart 2.x

Tags: javascript, open-flash-chart

To my way of thinking I need to use tooltip like the tooltip in 1.x and the magicword #tip# 's function.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can try these two links:

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/tooltip.php

http://pullmonkey.com/2008/7/28/open-flash-chart-ii-multi-bar-graph-with-tooltips